# Pandas: Detect single words that have certain length

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In my.csv file I'm trying to detect and pull rows that have long single words (it can either be one word, or multiple words but one of them is super long) - please note im not looking for the total char in the string but only long words detection so this for example won't work for me: `longtitles = df['name'].str.len() > 15` .

Below my example, however would be great if there is universal solution that works with any string also with numeric values and special character values.

my.csv

```
  id      name
  1       this is my sample value
  2       thisismysecondsamplevalue
  3       this ismythirdsamplevalue
```

My criteria: Find rows with words that are greater than 15chars and pull to output.csv

output.csv

```
  id      name
  2       thisismysecondsamplevalue
  3       this ismythirdsamplevalue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.split` with `unstack`:

```
length = df['name'].str.split(expand=True).unstack().str.len()
m = length.unstack(level=0).gt(15).any(axis=1)
out = df[m]

   id                       name
1   2  thisismysecondsamplevalue
2   3  this ismythirdsamplevalue
```

Using `str.split` with `apply` (slower version)

```
m = df['name'].str.split(expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()) > 15
out = df[m.any(axis=1)]

   id                       name
1   2  thisismysecondsamplevalue
2   3  this ismythirdsamplevalue
```

Answer (score 4):

One way using `pandas.Series.extract`:

```
mask = df["name"].str.findall("(\S{16,})").astype(bool)
print(df[mask])
```

Output:

```
   id                       name
1   2  thisismysecondsamplevalue
2   3  this ismythirdsamplevalue
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement it your self.
Example:

```py
def has_too_long_word(text):
    return max([len(x) for x in text.split()]) > 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out following example using lambda function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['efg efg', 'qwertyujkmnbvc', 'werty tyu']})
mask = df.a.str.split().apply( lambda x: max( len(y) for y in x ) ) > 10
select  = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to build the filter you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

filter = df['name'].apply(lambda x: any([True if len(word)> 15 else False for word in x.split(' ')]))

print(df[filter])
```

Output:

```
   id                       name
1   2  thisismysecondsamplevalue
2   3  this ismythirdsamplevalue
```

**Explanation**

You use `apply` to map the `lambda` function to each element of `'name'` columns. Through the `lambda` function, you split the string by whitespaces and put the chunks in a list; for each chunk, you check if its length is more than `15`. If there is at least one element in the string that fulfills this requirements you get a `True`, `False` otherwise.
Finally, you can filter your dataframe through the `filter` just created.

---

**Benchmark**

Here I report a performance comparison between the solutions here reported. It could be useful in case of large dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import timeit

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def profiling(function):
    def timer(*args):
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        matrix = function(*args)
        stop = timeit.default_timer()
        duration = stop - start
        print(f'Time = {round(duration*1e3, 2)} ms')
        return matrix
    return timer

@profiling
def filter1():
    filter = df['name'].apply(lambda x: any([True if len(word)> 15 else False for word in x.split(' ')]))
    return df[filter]

@profiling
def filter2():
    m = df['name'].str.split(expand = True).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()) > 15
    return df[m.any(axis = 1)]

@profiling
def filter3():
    mask = df["name"].str.findall("(\S{16,})").astype(bool)
    return df[mask]

@profiling
def filter4():
    mask = df.name.str.split().apply(lambda x: max(len(y) for y in x)) > 10
    return df[mask]

filter1()
filter2()
filter3()
filter4()
```

Results:

```
Time =  1.07 ms
Time = 12.18 ms
Time =  1.96 ms
Time =  2.21 ms
```

The `filter1` is the most efficient, `filter3` is close to `filter1`; `filter2` is the less efficient.